# background image using report lab?

Tags: image, pdf, reportlab

how can i add background image to pdf pages using reportlab?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have PIL (Python Imaging Library) installed, you can use `canvas.drawImage`.  To make a background image, just call `drawImage` before anything else on the page and it will be drawn first:  then everything else will draw on top of it.

You can find out more about this function on page 15 of the [ReportLab Manual](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf).