# reportlab: add background image by using platypus

Tags: python, image, reportlab, platypus

this is a bit related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138301/background-image-using-report-lab)

I am trying to place an image on the background, and I want to be able to write text over it.
using `canvas.drawImage` helps, but that's too low level approach for me. 
My program uses platypus, but `canvas.drawImage` is part of different library.
I've been able to insert images with `platypus.Image`, but couldn't figure out how to make it as background.
Any advice would be great,

Thanks
D

Answer (score 12):

When you create a page template in Platypus you have the ability to pass a function via the named argument `onPage`.  In that function you can place all your basic page formatting (headers, footers, watermark, background image).

Here's an example:

```
def AllPageSetup(canvas, doc):

    canvas.saveState()

    #header
    canvas.drawString(0.5 * inch, 8 * inch, doc.fund.name)
    canvas.drawRightString(10.5 * inch, 8 * inch, doc.report_info)

    #footers
    canvas.drawString(0.5 * inch, 0.5 * inch, 'Larry Co.')
    canvas.drawRightString(10.5 * inch, 0.5 * inch, 'Page %d' % (doc.page))

    canvas.setFont("Helvetica", 240)
    canvas.setStrokeGray(0.90)
    canvas.setFillGray(0.90)
    canvas.drawCentredString(5.5 * inch, 3.25 * inch, doc.watermark)

    canvas.restoreState()

doc = BaseDocTemplate(file_name)

doc.fund = fund # stores my fund object into the document for reference
doc.report_info = "%s %s" % (fund.current_report.date.isoformat(), version)
doc.watermark = 'DRAFT'

page_template = PageTemplate(id="fund_notes", onPage=AllPageSetup, pagesize=page_size)

#Now, every page will have headers, footers, and a watermark
```

Comment: If you are using `SimpleDocTemplate` to build your document, you can  pass the page setup function to the `build` method: `doc.build(story, onFirstPage=AllPageSetup, onLaterPages=AllPageSetup)`

Comment: how to add a canvas.drawimage with a filename and fits to the full pagesize??